# Using sublime text 3 to edit Anaconda python code on windows

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

I am trying to run `import pandas` code via Anacondas' python executable, in sublime text 3, and receive the following error message...

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\<dir>\<python_file>.py", line 1, in <module>
>           import pandas as pd
>         File "C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
>           "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
>       ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

I can import pandas, and run other code when using spyder, but am struggling to get the environment setup in sublime. I have followed the two tutorials below, however I'm not having any luck.

- [Using Anaconda On Sublime Text (without installing any package)](https://dev.to/abdurrahmaanj/using-anaconda-on-sublime-text-39le)
- [Anaconda Documentation: Sublime text](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/sublime/)

any suggestions/advice is much appreciated!

`import pandas as pd`

Comment: Sublime Text, as I know is a text editor. Are you running through the command line?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit strange you can import pandas in Spydrr and get an error in Sublime. I cannot give a do-this answer, but I can suggest a review of concepts that you use for diagnostics:

- Sublime and Spider are text editors, they are to handle code themselves, but invoke python interpreter that is already installed on the system (eg Anaconda)
- sometimes you several python interpreters installed, would need to find out which has a precedence to appear in your path search
- same interpreter may work with different virtual environments (package sets), controlled by venv.

From your disgnostic message hard to tell which situation you are in. When in doubt, try play on the command line to run the python.exe and explore your PATH variable.

Hope it helps.